# Centering navbar icon text - Rails app using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a 4.x Rails app using Bootstrap.  The navbar has Font Awesome icons in it.  When you hover over an icon, a `<span>` with one word of text appears **below** the icon.

The problem I am having is getting this one word of text to be **centered horizontally below** the icon.  Right now the icon is stacked above the text, as it should be; however, the text is aligned to the left, not aligned with the horizontal center of the icon.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li id="nav-microphone"><%= link_to '#', class: "col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-2" do %>
      <i class="fa fa-microphone fa-3x"></i><br>
      <span class="nav-icon-text">mute</span>
      <% end %>
    </li>
    <li id="nav-video"><%= link_to '#', class: "col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-2" do %>
      <i class="fa fa-video-camera fa-3x"></i><br>
      <span class="nav-icon-text">off</span>
      <% end %>
    </li>
    <li id="nav-exit"><%= link_to '#', class: "col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-2" do %>
      <i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-3x"></i><br> 
      <span class="nav-icon-text">hangup</span>
      <% end %>
    </li>
    <li id="nav-settings"><%= link_to '#', class: "col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-2" do %>
      <i class="fa fa-cog fa-3x"></i><br> 
      <span class="nav-icon-text">settings</span>
      <% end %>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my associated CSS:

```
.navbar {
  min-height: 80px;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: #98172c;
  border-color: #98172c;
}

.fa {
  color: white;
}

.mojo-logo {
  max-height: 60px;
}

#nav-microphone, #nav-video, #nav-exit {
  display: none;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.nav-icon-text {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Garamond Pro;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a:hover .nav-icon-text {
  display: block;   
}

.nav > li > a {
  padding: 10px 22px;
}

.nav > li {
  padding-top: 10px;
  min-height: 99px;
  min-width: 95px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

How can I get each `<span class="nav-icon-text">` to be **centered horizontally below** its associated icon?  Thanks!

Comment: I think you would be more likely to receive help if you had a working example online (at jsfiddle.net or a similar service).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HPJAJ**, Hi there. Try using `line-height: XXpx;` and make the this value the same px height as your icon. This is a easy way to get your text in the middle vertically. I also think the`<span>` may have some `padding-top` too, so keep this in mind.

**Added to post**

**Roger that, you meant horizontally.**

I put your code up and found that you have an issue with having those `col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-2` in the navbar.
For this demo, I turned on the parts you were not displaying. Like the text and the icons.

Removing the classes showed that your text was centered.

As you will see in this code below.

Here is a working **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/mh9xenef/)**.

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
  
    
.navbar {
  min-height: 80px;
  border-radius: 0;  
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: #98172c;
  border-color: #98172c;
}

.fa {
  color: white;
}

.mojo-logo {
  max-height: 60px;
}

#nav-microphone, #nav-video, #nav-exit {
  display: block;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.nav-icon-text {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Garamond Pro;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a:hover .nav-icon-text {
  display: block;
  color:darkorange;    
}

.nav > li > a {
  padding: 10px 0px;
  
}

.nav > li {
  padding-top: 10px;
  min-height: 99px;
  min-width: 95px;
  text-align: center;
}    
    
</style>

</head>

<body>

    
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-default">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
    <li id="nav-microphone"><a href="#" >
      <i class="fa fa-microphone fa-3x"></i><br>
      <span class="nav-icon-text">mute</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="nav-video"><a href="#" >
      <i class="fa fa-video-camera fa-3x"></i><br>
      <span class="nav-icon-text">off</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="nav-exit"><a href="#" >
      <i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-3x"></i><br> 
      <span class="nav-icon-text">hangup</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="nav-settings"><a href="#" >
      <i class="fa fa-cog fa-3x"></i><br> 
      <span class="nav-icon-text">settings</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was not clear in my original explanation that it needs to be horizontally centered, not vertically.  I edited the question accordingly. Thanks @AngularJR !

Comment: Hi, that's ok. I took another look at your code here. See the update in the main post.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks @AngularJR !!